# Python: kedro viz SQLAlchemy DeprecationWarning

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, dependencies, kedro

I tried to work with kedro and started with the spaceflight tutorial.
I installed the src/requirements.txt in a .venv.
When running `kedro viz` (or `kedro run` or even `kedro --version`), I get lets of Deprecation Warnings.
One of which is the following (relating to kedro viz)

```
kedro_viz\models\experiment_tracking.py:16: MovedIn20Warning: [31mDeprecated API features          warnings.py:109                             detected! These feature(s) are not compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.0. [32mTo prevent incompatible upgrades prior to updating applications, ensure requirements files
                             are pinned to "sqlalchemy<2.0". [36mSet environment variable SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 to show all deprecation warnings.  Set environment variable
                             SQLALCHEMY_SILENCE_UBER_WARNING=1 to silence this message.[0m (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)
                               Base = declarative_base()
```

### Context

This is a minor issue, but ofc I would like to setup the project to be as clean as possible.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Setup a fresh kedro installation (Version 0.18.4)
2. Create a .venv and install the standard requirements
3. Run any kedro command (e.g. `kedro --version`)

### What I've tried

I tried to put `sqlalchemy<=2.0` in the requirements.txt and again run `pip install -r src/requirements.txt`,
but that did not resolve it. Double checked with `pip freeze` that the following version of SQLAlchemy is installed:
`SQLAlchemy==1.4.46`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deprecation warning is not an issue, it's just a announcement from the SQLAlchemy folks that 2.x.x is coming, at the time it's writing it's not been released.

`kedro-viz` is pinned to `sqlalchemy~=1.4` or (some of the datasets use `"SQLAlchemy~=1.2"`). The `~=` operator is basically the same as saying `sqlalchemy >= 1.4, <2`. We will look to relax this once 0.2.x is released and we test if anything needs fixing.

Comment: We've now got an action on our backlog to fix on our end as best we can
https://github.com/kedro-org/kedro/issues/2202